# Fileupload control always returning Hasfile property false

Tags: html, asp.net

i am trying to upload the file ,but the upload control returning always false , due to which file my code below doesn't work.  I am submitting the  storing the file in database in button event. can anyone tell me please where i am going wrong.

Thanks

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <asp:Label ID="lblPhoto" runat="server" Text="Photo"></asp:Label>
  <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
</div>
```

```
    if (fileupload.HasFile)
  {
     HttpPostedFile postedfile = fileupload.PostedFile;
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);
    string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    if (fileextension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileextension.ToLower() == ".bmp" || fileextension.ToLower() == ".gif" || fileextension.ToLower() == ".png")
       {

        Stream stream = fileupload.postedfile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        photodata = binaryreader.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);

       }
       else
         {
        LblRegisterStatus.Text = "Only files with(.jpg .bmp .gif .png) can be uploaded";
        LblRegisterStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Add your `page_load` method too

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                  if (!IsPostBack)
                    {
                        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
                    }
            Alumni_lblStatus.Text = "";
      }

Answer (score 2):

you can use file upload by jquery too

**JS Function**

```
function SaveFiles() {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var file = $("#fileInput").val();

    if (file.length > 0) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/Admin/UploadImage');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');

        //Appending file information in Http headers
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', fileInput.files[0].name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', fileInput.files[0].type);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', fileInput.files[0].size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader['X-File-FileName', 1];
        xhr.setRequestHeader['X-File-Id', id];

        //Sending file in XMLHttpRequest
        xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {

            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

                alert("Image Uploaded Successfully...");

            }
        }
    }
}

**C# Code**

public JsonResult UploadImage()
        {
            string fileName = Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
            string fileType = Request.Headers["X-File-Type"];
            int fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Headers["X-File-Size"]);

            System.IO.Stream fileContent = Request.InputStream;
            System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImg/" + fileName));
            fileContent.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //Copying file's content to FileStream
            fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();

            string FileName = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImg/" + fileName);

            //Here you can code for insert in database

            return Json(FileName);
        }
```

Comment: i am using multiview all the details i am saving , including the picture upload is on button click

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload control is not compatible with UpdatePanel. You have two options

1. Move the control outside of UpdatePanel.
2. If not possible, add a PostBackTrigger on the UpdatePanel
   An example
   FileUpload control is not compatible with UpdatePanel. You have two options

Move the control outside of UpdatePanel
If not possible, add a PostBackTrigger on the UpdatePanel
An example

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="yourButtonIdThatSubmitsFile" />
</Triggers>
```